# Which kind of key I need?

Tags: sql-server, unique-key

I have a table `Page`. Every record in this table have a primary id.

Now, I have a table Photos, with has:

- `id` for each record.
- `idPage` which refers to a page.

I need a sort of key in the table `Photos` : so, when I add the same record on the table Photo with `id` and `idPage` twice, it doesn't add it twice.

I know in MySql is `UNIQUE` key. What is in SQL Server? And how can I create it?

Answer (score 0):

If your id is a primary key, it must already be unique and you won't be able to have the same photo on more than one page. You probably want a join table PhotosPages with a PK of (idPhoto,idPage) rather than storing the idPage directly in the Photos table.

Alternatively, you can create a [unique index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187019.aspx) on (idPage,id).  This would probably be appropriate because idPage is a foreign key for pages and having the index would certainly speed up any joins that you would do.  A [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx) is another possibility, but an index is more useful, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

On your Photos table, use id and idPage together as a composite key.  That will prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [`CONSTRAINT UNIQUE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx), since the primary key `id` is unique by default, so all you need to keep the two compination `id` and `pageid` is add to the `pageid` a `CONSTRAINT UNIQUE`. Which will be equivilant to setting the `id` and `pageid` together as *Composite key*.